# Creating a NodeJS + Mongo DB MVC, any ideas how to start?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, node.js, mongodb

I use PHP with most of my projects/startups, I'm thinking of moving into NodeJS because I heard it's cool, I just need few tips or links to start with creating an MVC in NodeJS and MongoDb.

Comment: Do you want to use or adapt an existing MVC framework or make your own from nothing?

Comment: Would like to know how to do from scratch and why not using something like express.js

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://railwayjs.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express and MongoDB are pretty great. Do this.
1) Make sure you're great with JS and understand the module system in node.
2) Go take the 5-10 minute interactive tutorial over at http://mongodb.org/
3) install node (includes npm)
4) install express as a global (npm install -g express)
    express --sessions --css stylus --ejs myapp

and you have pretty awesome scaffold that is super easy to understand.
5) Have fun!

As a word of advice, if you find mongoose not too friendly try using mongoJS. it's simpler and easier, but doesn't have some of the advanced features of mongoose

Answer (score 3):

Try these tools: [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) for mongodb and [Express](http://expressjs.com/) for MVC.

Comment: This is the defacto standard for mongodb and node.js if you want schemas